# angular2 ngfor array of objects error in template

Tags: java, angularjs, angular, ngfor

I am now experimenting with angular2. I want to show the all product list in a view. The productlist I am getting from Java Play server. But in my angular2 view its showing error can not bind ngFor. the console.log is showing all the data in array of Object form. Thats mean my angular component can get data from java server.  Here is my approach.

products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Logger } from 'angular2-logger/core';

import { ProductService }         from './products.service';
import { ProductsModule }         from './products.module';

@Component({
    selector: 'products-cmp',
    templateUrl:    'assets/app/portal/common/products/products.component.html',
providers: [ ProductService, ProductsModule ],
})

export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    private products: Object;
    private keys: String[];
    constructor(
        private productService: ProductService,
    ) {
    }

    public getAllProducts() {
      this.productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(
            products => {
                this.products = products;
                //this.keys = Object.keys(this.products);
                console.log(this.products);
                //console.log(this.keys);
            },
        );
}

public ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProducts();
}

}
```

products.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
// private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
private productsUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/api/products';
constructor(private http: Http) { }

public getProducts() {
    return this.http.get(this.productsUrl)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });

}

}
```

products.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { PipesModule } from '../../../pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ PipesModule, BrowserModule ],
    exports: [ BrowserModule, PipesModule ],
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

products.component.html

```
<div class="main-content">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row" *ngFor="let product of products"  >
        {{product.productName}}
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Banging my head for couple of hours. would be great if anyone kindly help me to solve this problem

** This is a sample of my get data

```
Array[110]
[0 … 99]
0:Object
  actualPrice:10
  companyProductId:"1"
  estimateUnitdPrice:11
  id:"fde96cc0-a9de-48d8-9229-e62088f8e570"
  productImageUrl:null
  productName:"TEST"
  whenCreated:1488466833952
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
```

This is app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }      from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Logger } from 'angular2-logger/core';
import { PipesModule } from './pipes/pipes.module';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { PortalComponent } from './portal/portal.component';

import { PortalModule } from './portal/portal.module';
import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './shared/footer/footer.module';
import { NavbarModule} from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';

@NgModule({
imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    PortalModule,
    SidebarModule,
    NavbarModule,
    FooterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
],
declarations: [ AppComponent, PortalComponent ],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
providers:      [ Logger, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here I have added a snippet of my json response from server

```
[{"id":"fde96cc0-a9de-48d8-9229-e62088f8e570","version":1,"whenCreated":1488466833952,"whenUpdated":1488466833952,"productName":"TEST","shopReference":"ALDI_SUD","estimateUnitdPrice":11.0,"productImageUrl":null,"actualPrice":10.0,"units":1,"companyProductId":"1"},{"id":"6d1d231a-cfbd-4040-abd6-fb393974cc59","version":1,"whenCreated":1488467046104,"whenUpdated":1488467046104,"productName":"TEST","shopReference":"ALDI_SUD","estimateUnitdPrice":11.0,"productImageUrl":null,"actualPrice":10.0,"units":1,"companyProductId":"1"},......]
```

Comment: can you try defining your products like this `private products: any;`?

Comment: What is the exact error that is thrown?

Comment: same error using any :

Comment: zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Can you post your app.module code? Is BrowserModule in the imports?

Comment: I think products should be set to an array, not a singleton "Object". Also, defining a Product class would help too.

Comment: <div class="row" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let product of products;" >
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            "): ProductsComponent@4:25
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "directives" section.

Comment: post the JSON response from `/api/products`

Comment: I have just added the json response /api/products at the question

Comment: can you try importing product.module in your app.module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont't import `BrowserModule` in feature modules like `ProductsModule`, import it only in the root module `AppModule`.

Add the `CommonModule` to `imports` property of feature modules in this case `ProductsModule` and remove it from `AppModule`'s imports property, because `BrowserModule` itself exports `CommonModule` so we don't need to import it again.

// ProductsModule

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }      from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    declarations : [ ProductsComponent ],
    exports: [ ProductsComponent ]
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

//AppModule

```
@NgModule({
imports:      [
    ProductsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    PortalModule,
    SidebarModule,
    NavbarModule,
    FooterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
],
declarations: [ AppComponent, PortalComponent ],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
providers:      [ Logger, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the `ProductsComponent` must be declared and exported in the `ProductsModule`, the `ProductsModule` should be imported in the `AppModule`.

that's gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import `CommonModule` instead of `BrowserModule`. See this section in documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module

Comment: I have added app.module.ts in my question